# Oracle SQL: Return a string based on which column has the highest value

Tags: sql, oracle

The tabled I am presented with looks similar to this

```
CREATE TABLE user_status (
  user_id NUMBER(10,0) PRIMARY KEY,  
  applied TIMESTAMP,
  joined TIMESTAMP,
  last_attended TIMESTAMP,
  quit TIMESTAMP
);
```

The database is Oracle 11g.

What SQL query could use if I would like to return APPLIED, JOINED, ACTIVE or INACTIVE based on whether applied, joined, last_attended or quit is the latest and the respective date.

It is also acceptable if I can get the name of the column (instead of APPLIED, JOINED, ACTIVE or INACTIVE) that has the latest date, if that greatly simplifies the query.

Sample rows:

```
1 | 28-JUL-15 03.37.07 PM | 29-JUL-15 03.37.07 PM | 30-JUL-15 03.37.07 PM | (null)
2 | 18-JUL-15 03.55.24 PM | 19-JUL-15 03.55.24 PM | 20-JUL-15 03.55.24 PM | 31-JUL-15 03.55.24 PM
```

Expected result:

```
1 | ACTIVE | 30-JUL-15 03.37.07 PM
2 | INACTIVE | 31-JUL-15 03.55.24 PM
```

**Update**

Here's the solution I have based on Gordon Linoff's answer:

```
select (case greatest(coalesce(applied, to_date('0001-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')), 
                      coalesce(joined, to_date('0001-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')),
                      coalesce(last_attended, to_date('0001-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')),
                      coalesce(quit, to_date('0001-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')))
             when applied 
             then 'APPLIED'
             when joined
             then 'JOINED'
             when last_attended
             then 'INACTIVE'
             when quit
             then 'QUIT'
             else null
        end) as status, greatest(coalesce(applied, to_date('0001-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')), 
                      coalesce(joined, to_date('0001-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')),
                      coalesce(last_attended, to_date('0001-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')),
                      coalesce(quit, to_date('0001-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))) as status_date
from user_status;
```

Comment: Sample data and expected result

Comment: Added and also corrected the question

Comment: In the case of all four columns being `null`, do you really want January 1, 1 for `status_date`?

Comment: Thans for that!  Updated the query to return null for this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all have values, you can do:

```
select us.*
       (case when applied = greatest(applied, joined, last_attended, quit)
             then 'Applied'
             when joined = greatest(applied, joined, last_attended, quit)
             then 'Joined'
             when last_attended = greatest(applied, joined, last_attended, quit)
             then 'Last Attended'
             else 'Quit'
        end)
from user_status us
```

If these could have `NULL` values, then you need more complex logic, because `greatest()` returns `NULL` if any argument is `NULL`.  Assuming all are in the past, then something like this:

```
select (case greatest(coalesce(applied, date '0000-01-01'), 
                      coalesce(joined, date '0000-01-01'),
                      coalesce(last_attended, date '0000-01-01'),
                      coalesce(quit, date '0000-01-01') )
             when applied 
             then 'Applied'
             when joined
             then 'Joined'
             when last_attended
             then 'Last Attended'
             else 'Quit'
        end)
from . . .
```

Comment: Stylistically, I prefer `date '0001-01-01'` instead of `sysdate + 1`.I think it communicates the intention of producing a value that will not match anything.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance . . . More important than style, that is the correct logic in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
select user_id, case greatest(applied, joined, last_attended, quit)
    when applied then 'APPLIED'
    when joined then 'JOINED'
    when last_attended then 'ACTIVE'
    when quit then 'INACTIVE' end
from user_status
```

In the event of a tie between fields, the first field in the `case` expression wins.

Comment: is it possible to account for null values in these date column and also return the date value for the latest?  Small typo: string INACTIVE is not closed.

Comment: @akirekadu, `greatest(applied, joined, last_attended, quit)` will give the date value of the latest. See the use of `coalesce` with impossible answer in @Gordon Linoff's answer to eliminate nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
SELECT 'APPLIED', MAX(applied) as val from user_status
  UNION ALL
SELECT 'JOINED', MAX(joined) as val  from user_status
  UNION ALL
SELECT 'ACTIVE', MAX(last_attended) as val  from user_status
  UNION ALL
SELECT 'INACTIVE', MAX(quit) as val from user_status
```

for example

> you probably want to restrict this to a particular user in the
>   innermost query...

```
SELECT what 
FROM (
  SELECT what 
  FROM ( 
    SELECT 'APPLIED' as what, MAX(applied) as val from user_status
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'JOINED' as what, MAX(joined) as val  from user_status
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ACTIVE' as what, MAX(last_attended) as val  from user_status
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'INACTIVE' as what, MAX(quit) as val from user_status
  ) sub
  ORDER BY val DESC  
) sub2
WHERE rownum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it slightly different than others .. the advantage of this method is I'm also retrieving the data with it (if needed) .. ;)

```
  insert into user_status values ( 123, sysdate-10, sysdate-9, sysdate-8, sysdate-7 );
  insert into user_status values ( 234, sysdate-6, sysdate-1, sysdate-11, sysdate-16 );
  insert into user_status values ( 345, sysdate-5, sysdate-2, sysdate-12, sysdate-15 );
  insert into user_status values ( 456, sysdate-4, sysdate-3, sysdate-13, sysdate-14 );

  commit;

  with w_union as ( 
        select applied  dt, 'APPLIED' col, user_id
          from user_status
         union all
        select joined   dt, 'JOINED' col, user_id
          from user_status
         union all
        select last_attended  dt, 'LAST_ATTENDED' col, user_id
          from user_status
         union all
        select quit  dt, 'QUIT' col, user_id
          from user_status
     ),
     w_sub as (
        select  dt, col, user_id,
                row_number() over (order by dt desc) rnum
          from w_union
        )
  select dt, col, user_id
    from w_sub
   where rnum = 1
  /


  DT                             COL              USER_ID
  ------------------------------ ------------- ----------
  30-JUL-15 01.33.12.000000 PM   JOINED               234
```